# AVR windows application

Tags: windows, avr

I would like to make an Windows application that receives an .hex file and than it uploads to an AVR microcontroller (in my case ATmega88p) via a programmer (like Pocket AVR Programmer or similar) .

I need to be able to send a new .hex file to the application but the application should not be able to change the .hex.  Does something like that already exist?

I searched if visual studio has any library to send data to an microcontroller but I did not find any useful hint.

Thank you for your time.

EDIT:
As suggested my problem using different words:

I want an standalone application that is able to send .hex data via a simple programmer to a microcontroller (ATmega88p).
Where should I start?  I have some experience in .NET. Is it possible in Visual studio? Does something like that already exist?

Comment: Thanks for correcting it. I'd suggest you re-word your question a bit to say something like *"How do I send data to my microcontroller....[fill in the blanks]"*. Asking for a library etc is generally off topic, you are better off asking **how to do** something instead.

Comment: Is it possible to make an app that when needed call avrdude (or something similar) and tells it to program the microcontroler with the selected .hex file? How would I do that?

Comment: It would be possible (and how to do it) with an web application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[avrdude](http://www.nongnu.org/avrdude/) is a preexisting application that is able to program to a number of AVR micro controllers through a number of different interfaces. This is a console application. While I don't have experience with Visual Studio, I imagine most IDEs are able to call a command line application with the appropriate arguments.

In this case, avrdude needs to know which chip you're using (`-p`), which programming interface is connected to the chip (`-c`), and where the hex file is (`-U`). In your case, you're using the ATMega88p, so you'll pass `-p m88p`, a pocket programmer (which is essentially a USBTiny): `-Pusb -c usbtiny`, and the command to *write* your micro controller's *flash*, so `-U flash:w:path\to/your/file.hex`

The whole command looks like this:

`avrdude -Pusb -c usbtiny -p m88p -U flash:w:path\to\your\file.hex`

You can learn more by reading ladyada's [AVRDUDE tutorial](http://ladyada.net/learn/avr/avrdude.html)